# Openpdf maven install gives error, but compile step was successful

Tags: java, openpdf

I am trying to install an open pdf build locally using Eclipse.

I cloned the GIT repo to a local folder and opened the project.

I set up a run configuration with these maven targets: `clean compile package`

Everything seems to have gone well, these lines output at the end:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for OpenPDF - Free and Open PDF 1.3.31-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] OpenPDF - Free and Open PDF ........................ SUCCESS [  0.750 s]
[INFO] openpdf ............................................ SUCCESS [ 25.441 s]
[INFO] pdf-swing .......................................... SUCCESS [  3.820 s]
[INFO] pdf-toolbox ........................................ SUCCESS [  8.198 s]
[INFO] openpdf-fonts-extra ................................ SUCCESS [  3.043 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to install the packages to my local Maven repository, so I changed the targets to `clean compile package install`
I received an error that it could not find a GPG key, so I added a gpg.skip parameter to my run config:
[image]

But now, I get what seems to be an unrelated compilation error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (compile-java-9) on project openpdf: Compilation failure Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[7,24] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.bouncycastle
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[8,24] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[9,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.alignment
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[10,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.error_messages
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[11,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.exceptions
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[12,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.factories
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[13,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.html
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[14,34] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[15,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[16,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[17,39] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.wmf
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[18,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.collection
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[19,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.crypto
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[20,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.draw
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[21,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.events
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[22,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.fonts
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[23,39] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.fonts.cmaps
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[24,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.hyphenation
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[25,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[26,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.internal
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[27,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[28,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.utils
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[29,29] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.xml
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[30,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.xml.simpleparser
[ERROR] /C:/OneDrive/Dev/OpenPDF/openpdf/src/main/java9/module-info.java:[31,33] package is empty or does not exist: com.lowagie.text.xml.xmp
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to change my goals to `clean compile package install:install`